# Hiding the table view cells with switch ON/OFF in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

This may be a simple question for you experts but I can't figure out the correct solution.

In my app I created a a table view to list a no of items.

In the first row of the cell there a switch (`ON/OFF`).

So my client need to hide the bottom cells(other than zeroth cell) when switch is `OFF` and show all the cells when switch is `ON`.

I created the switch through code.

Can anyone please help me with how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

numberOfRows dataSource method - make it return 1 and reloadTableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  /// ....
            self.switchView = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];
            cell.accessoryView = self.switchView;
            [self.switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
            [self.switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//....

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if [self.switchView.on]
       return 1;
   else 
   {
      // normal code return
   }
}

- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @mbh, it's a UITableVIewDataSource method, not a delegate method.

Comment: Can we not hide and show the below cells with little animation, alike to iOS native settings app?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, this will not only add, but also do the animation of adding new row

first add target `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` into `UISwitch`.

`[switch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

> -(void) switchChange:(UISwitch*) sender{
>
> ```
>        isSwitchOn = sender.on; //edited
>     [myTable beginUpdates];
>     NSIndexPath *row1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
>     NSIndexPath *row2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
>     //you may add as many row as you want here.
>
>     [myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1,row2,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
>     [myTable endUpdates];
> ```
>
> }

and make sure you will add how many rows you will insert in `numberOfRowsInSection:`

> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
>     {
>
>   if (isSwitchOn)  return 1;
>
>   else
>      return 3; //how many rows would have after switched on
>
> }

You might want to check `[myTable insertSections:withRowAnimation:` to insert another section and do the same as above. but remember to state how many section you will add, in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

UPDATE :

implement `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` if switch off.

> -(void) switchChange:(UISwitch*) sender{
>
> ```
>     isSwitchOn = sender.on;
>
>   if(isSwitchOn){
>         [myTable beginUpdates];
>          NSIndexPath *row1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
>          NSIndexPath *row2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
>          //you may add as many row as you want here.
>
>         [myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1,row2,nil]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
>         [myTable endUpdates];
>     }
>   else{
>         [myTable beginUpdates];
>          NSIndexPath *row1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
>          NSIndexPath *row2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
>          //you may add as many row as you want here.
>
>         [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1,row2,nil]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
>         [myTable endUpdates]; 
>  }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

There's a UITableViewDataSource method called tableView:numberOfRows:inSections method.Just check for the state of the switch and return 1 if it's OFF or all the rows if it is ON. Just call the [tableView reloadData] method each time you switch ON and OFF. As simple as that.

Comment: When reloadData method's called it causes the following methods to be called in order: 1.  tableView:numberOfSections:   2 tableView:numberOfRows:inSection:   3. tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: methodfs. So you have to call it when you switch ON and OFF.