# How to reload tableview after adding new entry?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cloudkit

I am creating a cloudkit tableview. I load the app and my tableview appears with my entries from cloud kit.

I then use my add method `insertNewObject` which adds the record to cloud kit but this does not show up in my tableview. It will only show up on my next run of the app.

```
   func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "CloudNote")
    record.setObject("New Note", forKey: "Notes")

    MyClipManager.SaveMethod(Database!, myRecord:record)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    }
```

This is my add method. I am calling tableview reload as you can see but nothing is happening.

My tableview creation code:

```
    // Tableview stuff --- Done

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
        /////// Get number of rows
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}
        //// FIll the table
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] 
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.objectForKey("Notes") as? String
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
```

As requested: Method that saves to CloudDB

```
   func SaveMethod(publicDatabase: CKDatabase, myRecord: CKRecord ) -> CKRecord {

    publicDatabase.saveRecord(myRecord, completionHandler:
        ({returnRecord, error in
            if let err = error {
                self.notifyUser("Save Error", message:
                    err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.notifyUser("Success",
                        message: "Record saved successfully")
                }


            }
        }))
 return myRecord
}
```

My viewdidload method in masterview:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Database loading on runtime
        Database = container.privateCloudDatabase

        ///Build Query
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "CloudNote", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"))

        ///Perform query on DB
        Database!.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (records, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error performing query. \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }

            self.objects = records!

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
```

Comment: what does this method,     MyClipManager.SaveMethod(Database!, myRecord:record) do??

Comment: `reloadData` won't do anything useful unless you update your table view's data source. Where do you add an object to the `objects` array?

Comment: Hi i've added an update with my SaveMethod. it saves to the array in cloud kit.

Comment: Take a look at the my answer that can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408232/how-to-add-row-cells-dynamically-to-an-uitableview-by-pressing-a-button-in-iphon/24984185#24984185

Comment: @RafałAugustyniak this is in objective C, So i can't make heads or tails of it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not reload your entire tableView when you insert a single object. Only do that when you know ALL the data has changed.

To do what you want, this is the order:

1. - Insert a new data object into your datasource (self.objects). Make sure you get the index of where it ends up in the array.
2. - Call insertRowAtIndexPath: with the correct indexPath on your tableView. This will make sure your data and tableView are in sync again, and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called for at least your new data object (and possible others, as certain cells might now be reused to display other data).

Note that the order is always: update your data first, then update your UI (the only place I know of that his is hairy is when using a UISwitch).

Comment: thanks for the reply. this makes a lot of sense. One question:

how would I find out at which index my new record is inserted, I'm guessing this should be done in my save method and returned?

Comment: Yes, you can return it from your save method (make sure it is a method that `throws`, so that your dataSource knows when the method failed and should NOT insert a new row in the tableView). So basically: your newly created data object will end up in your `objects` variable. If this is a mutable array (do not use this across different threads!), then you can add your new data object via `insertAtIndex:` or `addObject:`. With the first you decide the index, with the last one the index will be the count before you added the object.